# Codeigniter 3 won't connect to MSSQL 2012 database under php 5.6 on Rackspace

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, rackspace, php-5.6

Our site is on Rackspace cloud sites and is currently running fine with Codeigniter 3.0.0 on PHP 5.4.1.0 and connecting to a MSSQL 2012 database.  Rackspace is in the process of upgrading PHP from 5.4.1.0 to 5.6.7-1 and has given testlinks for testing our websites in the new PHP environment. In this test environment, the site does not connect to the MSSQL database.  However - no errors are thrown (that I can find, anyway!)

This is what I have for my database configuration:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mssqlXXXX.XXX',
    'username' => 'USERNAME',
    'password' => 'PASSWORD',
    'database' => 'DATABASE NAME',
    'dbdriver' => 'mssql',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

As a test, Rackspace also had me write a test controller. It also fails in Codeigniter. Code follows:

```
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";
$hostname = 'mssqlXXXX.XXX';
$dbname = "DATABASE";

//connection to the database
$dbcon = mssql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)or die("Unable to connect to MSSQL");
echo "Connected to MSSQL";

//select the database
mssql_select_db($dbname, $dbcon);

//SQL Select statement
$sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";

//Run the SQL query
$sqlquery = mssql_query($sqlselect);

//Output the query results
while ($result = mssql_fetch_array($sqlquery) )
{
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

If I take this script out of the Codeigniter environment, it works.

I have tried changing my codeigniter database configuration as follows: hostname to an IP address instead of the Rackspace recommended value, changing the dbdriver to sqlsrv, using a dsn string instead of hostname and database and using the odbc database driver.  Nothing works.

I am open to any and all suggestions.

**EDIT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Rackspace says "issue with freetds, which is a library used my PHP's mssql module for connecting to MSSQL Databases; the issue appears to revolve around using passwords longer than 30 characters."

So - I shortened my password.  Now the test controller mentioned above works!  Hurrah!  BUT - the standard Codeigniter database connection does not.

Comment: What output did you get from the test script when run on rackspace

Comment: Unable to connect to MSSQL

Comment: Have they installed the sql server drivers etc? Or are you expected to do that?

Comment: Have they gone to a 64bit PHP? Not sure that there are sql server drivers for a 64bit environment

Comment: Would that info be available via phpinfo()?  If not - I will have to ask.

Comment: You might get a clue from phpinfo() but it wont tell you if the drivers are there,

Comment: Then I have to wait for their tech support people to answer. It may be a while....

Comment: Thats ok I am not in a rush

Comment: Try to connect by using the dsn string.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Rackspace and they have corrected it.